# Auto generate JPG thumbnails from a PDF in ExpressionEngine?

Tags: uploads, dynamic, thumbnails

Just wondering if it's possible to automatically create a .jpg file from a .pdf file when uploading.

I've been seeing a bunch ImageMagick suggestions, but my brain is too tired to grasp it tonight. I guess I'm wondering if there is any other solutions to get a scaled .jpg from a .pdf on upload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the JPGs for rendering on a page the [Thumber](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/thumber) add-on from ElectricPutty should do exactly what you need:

```
{exp:thumber:create src='/uploads/documents/yourfile.pdf' page='2' extension='jpg' height='250' class='awesome' title='Click to download' link='yes'}
```

Comment: But be aware that you need ImageMagick (is most likely already installed) and Ghostscript on the server.